# How to access a method from both a show page and an index page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

In my model, I have a method that returns a variable.

```
def do_something(param1, param2)
  #code
  return variable
end
```

I successfully call this method from a partial rendered in my show page. Like this:

```
<%= @user.do_something(param1, param2) %>
```

I want to call the same method from a partial rendered in my index page. But I'm running into errors. **edit:** an undefined method for class error.

I could copy and paste all my method code into a duplicative method like:

```
def self.do_something(param1, param2)
  #code
  return variable
end
```

and call it from the index page partial like this...

```
<%= User.do_something(param1, param2) %>
```

... but that's not DRY, and I know there's probably a more appropriate solution out there. I'm still learning rails mechanics, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: Seeing the partials and how you're calling each would be useful.

Comment: Errors would be usefull as well.  If you are calling one an instance of User and one on the class itself (@user.do_something vs User.do_something), that could be part of the problem.

Comment: @Joeyjoejoejr that is exactly the problem. The question is how to adapt the method for use in the index?

Comment: @s2t2.  If it's not instance dependent,  there is no reason to have it as an instance method.  You can delegate, like the answer below, or you can make a helper for use in the views.  It would go into the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file.  Also, on an index page you generally loop through instances of a model.  Your instance method will be available on all of those instances.

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up just calling the class method from the both the index and the show page.

Comment: UPDATE: Years later I have no clue what this question is about. Sorry community. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can use delegation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something param1, param2
    self.class.do_something param1, param2
  end

  def self.do_something param1, param2
    ...
    return variable
  end
end
```